# module to print barcodes with image or method to do this? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

**I want to make a program to print barcodes on an avery monarch monarch printer in c#.**

*I can't find a video on youtube that can help me.*

Comment: Use a barcode font.

Comment: You can use the [LEADTOOLS C# Barcode Library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode) to add a barcode to an image or document before printing (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor). You can find a tutorial on how to do this [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-write-1d-and-2d-barcodes-to-an-image.html).